# When I try cloning a repository from github i keep getting an error, anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

Tags: github, clone

I'm trying to clone a repository on github into a directory on my computer.

I'm on mac and when i run this code
git clone <git@github.com:melenagrilliot/coding-prework-2023.git>

I'm getting an error sh: parse error near `\n'

Anyone know what I could be doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

In the interest of covering all bases, I will assume you have already ran the command without the < >

```
git clone git@github.com:melenagrilliot/coding-prework-2023.git
```

If the above doesn't work, then it is not a git related issue. There is something wrong with your shell (sh). The issue might stem from the .profile file in your home directory. Can you please use the following command to copy the contents of your .profile file and share it here?

```
cat ~/.profile | pbcopy
```